# strange behavior with config.json file

Tags: iis, angular11

I have a `config.json` file as part of my Angular project .

```js
{
  "apiUrl": "https://foo/ApiService/api",
  "reCaptchav3SiteKey":"6BGtDSd4rAAAAAzZINmLH0dfVC-Wr5QrWQWcqOD0",
  "allowTestPage": "true"
}
```

It might be that I am missing something with the command: `ng build --prod` since I'm experiencing a strange behavior.
I am copying the `dist` folder to the IIS server, and when changing one the the config file attributes on the server itself, it seems like nothing happens and the IIS keep remember the old value.
I have also tried reset the IIS but no success, So I'm thinking perhaps it has something to the way I'm building the angular project and it has nothing to the IIS.

I am using angular/cli - 11.0.0

Comment: Clear the cache and try again, do you get any errors?

Comment: no errors. and clearinh cache didn't help

Comment: Are you in the same situation locally?

Comment: No. Locally it works as expected

Comment: Which attributes in the config file did you change? Can you show me detailed information?

Comment: for instance, I'd like to change the API url address.
While building the project, the url is my local API (localhost), and when uploading the `dist` folder to the IIS on AZURE, What I'd like to do is  just changing the API url address parameter, to the environment the project is located on.